# Calculating the time between the signal when its ON and when it gets OFF

Tags: arduino-uno

```
class Channel 
{
    private:
        uint8_t _pin;
        uint8_t _state;
        uint32_t _rise;
        uint32_t _fall;
        uint8_t _count;
        uint8_t _channel;

        static uint8_t channelCount;

        void display() 
        {
            uint32_t diff = (_fall - _rise) / 1000;
            uint32_t secs = diff % 60;
            uint32_t mins = diff / 60;
          //  Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print(_channel);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print(mins);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print(secs-4);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.println(_count);
        }

    public:
        Channel(int pin) : _pin(pin), _count(0) 
        {
            _pin = pin;
            _count = 0;
            _channel = channelCount;
            channelCount++;
        }
        void process() 
          {
            int s = digitalRead(_pin);
            if (s != _state) 
              {
                _state = s;
                if (s == LOW)  // Fell
                  { 
                    _fall = millis();
                    _count++;
                    display();
                  } 
                else 
                  {
                    _rise = millis();
                  }
                }
            }
        void begin() 
        {
            pinMode(_pin, INPUT);
        }
};

uint8_t Channel::channelCount = 0;

Channel channels[] = { 3,5 };
#define NUM_CHANNELS (sizeof(channels) / sizeof(channels[0]))

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Channel,Minutes,Seconds,Count");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_CHANNELS; i++) 
      {
        channels[i].begin();
      }
}

void loop() 
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_CHANNELS; i++) 
      {
        channels[i].process();
      }   
}
```

This code works normally in some cases, (i.e.) It provides the exact time between the signal when it's ON and when it gets OFF in seconds.

In some cases, it spits out a 10 digit number. The correct value follows the unknown number in the screenshot attached below [image: which was taken when the output is recorded]

Comment: bro that 10 digit is the 0xFFFFFFFF maximum value that an unsigned 32 bit integer can attain.

Comment: @Vaibhav: No, the maximum value is 4294967295. The value he is seeing is −4. C.f. Reezy's answer.

Comment: You have not yet explained why you have put the bug in there. I mean the "secs-4" instead of "secs".

Comment: The values which I get in seconds is four seconds more than the actual value. So I used "sec-4" instead of seconds

Answer (score 4):

I suspect secs is 0 sometimes, because of _rise being 0? In that case unsigned int subtraction causes this: secs(0) - 4 = -4 % 2^32, resulting in your 4294967292

Comment: Oh, but there will be at least one second for which the signal will last. (I'm getting 4294967292 three to four times for a single ON and OFF transition). Is there any other possibility that might cause this to appear?

Comment: I suggest tracer bullets, i.e. print out all the variables in the Display method.

Comment: Yeah but still seconds cant be zero in my case there will be atleast 4 to 5 seconds, so even if I remove that "-4", still I would be getting this number right?